# Storing byte array image using JPA2 in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to store an image in the database but when I read the value I am getting always null.

I've tried several combinations of following annotations but result is always same:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
private byte[] image;
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/WheelGoDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

When I use only `@Lob` I've noticed that using pgAdmin i see numeric value. Otherwise I see `binary data`. My questions are:

1. Is there reliable way to store and read binary data using JPA2?
2. Is there way to read binary data in postgres? Because right now I am not sure if they are even correctly stored.

Comment: What is the type of the column in PostgreSQL?  I would recommend ``BYTEA`` if the data is less than a few megabytes.  It typically maps cleaner into an ORM.  You might want to read [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1005584)

Comment: When I use anotations mentioned in my primary post the type is BYTEA. Do you know how to view/save its content?